# listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use -> No matter what port I use?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, port, ubuntu-20.04

NodeJS version: LTS 12.17 installed like this:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt install nodejs
```

I have a pretty weird issue:

One of my NodeJS app suddenly reports: `listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use` and it doesn't help anything no matter what port # I try to change it to?

The full trace-stack looks like this:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:6080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1498:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

I'm listening like this (_wl = a Winston logger instance):

```
> _server.listen(_port, '0.0.0.0', function () { _wl.info('SERVER STARTED! (listening on port # ' + _port + ')')});
```

I have just setup this AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04 instance - so I guess somehow it has something to do with this. It has been working for years on a lot of different instance earlier Windows (I guess I have never run it on Ubuntu earlier).

I  execute like like:

```
1. cd into folder
2. node ./server.js (I have also tried to use Sudo)
```

Can it have something to do with permissions?

I have tried to allow all in /out going traffic in the server atteched Security Group.

I have check that the firewall in Ubuntu 20.04 is disabled as well.

Also, on the same server I'm running a Python app which exposes a web socket server and the NodeJS app has no issue to subscribe to this connection...

And yes - I have tried to check all ports in use at the server and only few ports are in use.
The NodeJS app also try to expose a websocket server at a given port - but no matter what port I try to use I get the error above.

Comment: what node version are you using? try removing the host argument in listen API and check if that works once?

Comment: NodeJS LTS v. 12.17. I have just tried to use this  only: _server.listen(_port)  --> But it still reports: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::6080

Comment: I works 100% on all Windows machines  and have done so for years - but I just tested on a local development Ubuntu 18.04 machine and it reports the exact same error! So I guess it is not just something with my new setup - but with Ubuntu and NodeJS (my code syntax)?

Comment: Hmm.. Can you share some code where you are starting the app? May be we are missing something in the code that is not provided i the question.

Comment: Ahh! you answered it already!! :)

Comment: Yes! But thank you so much for trying to helping me out!  :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry!

I use express in my NodeJS apps and most of my apps contain the following line:

```
app.listen(port); // In this case port # 6080
```

Later on in the current app (in which I experience the issue described above) I initialize a web socket server as well like this:

```
const _server = require('http').createServer();
_server.on('request', app);
_server.listen(_port, '0.0.0.0', function () { _wl.info('WEB SOCKET SERVER STARTED! (listening on port # ' + _port + ')')});
```

in the code above both `port` and `_port` used the same ENV variable/setting(6080). Do to my app/Express in this case actually didn't use the `app.listen(port)` to anything and that Windows just choose to overrule the port's use-case when the web socket server afterwards got initialized with the same port number --> is the reason why I never have experienced any issues on Windows. But Linux/Ubuntu is more sensitive in this regard.

Cheers! :-)